# Hyperlink text started changing and/or jumping to the right when clicked

Tags: html, css

The Hyperlink texts on both my site html and php pages (thousands) were working fine for a long time, then suddenly a few days ago they started acting strange. No scripts are used with the links: just html (a few links contain php in the address) and css (external style sheet). This happens in all browsers.

1. All links started jumping to the right when clicked (with or without font change), and
2. Some links that are placed in table divs: started causing the divs to dramatically enlarge and/or move when clicked (with or without font change), and
3. Some links started changing the font: size, spacing, colour and decoration when hovered and/or clicked, and
4. Some link text/font started acting erratically (shaking) when hovered, and
5. Some links still work (when font and/or position changes) and some don't.

Additionally: I have a pure CSS drop down horizontal menu, the links on the menu seem fine, but not long after the site link issue started...all the menu drop downs remained dropped down (wouldn't close).

Site was built years ago using Dreamweaver 5&6 . A couple months ago I copy-pasted the home page and site CSS to an external style sheet, worked fine. Then recently I tried adding or editing a single css style using Dreamweaver and all the problems started.

I searched for days and couldn't find any topics related to this, I had to temporarily redirect the whole site to an "under maintenance" page.

Comment: So how you want help without providing any code or any example?

Comment: Just looking for tips on where to look for causes of such a problem, as I had run out of ideas. Providing hundreds of pages of code may not be practical.

Comment: we can't help you without any code, at least provide some parts of your code where the problem occurs

Comment: at least give the website link

Comment: www.fishnbc.com , I removed the homepage (index) from the style page and rewrote the style back into the home page: this seems to have fixed almost all  of the problems and allows me to edit with Dreamweaver again.

Comment: ok, so you solved the problem ?

Comment: I still don't know what the problem was, but got it working by removing the home page from the external style sheet.  May have to remove the rest of the site from the external style sheet as well, if it happens again.